# Httppost different named view and action method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http-post

I have a view called "page.chtml" and I want to post from it to an action called "actionname"

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult actioname(...){...}
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use Html helper for creating a form with your desire submit action

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("actionName", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "FormId", name = "FormName" }))
{
   <div>//your page.cshtml inner html code goes here

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. In the `action` property of the form in page.cshtml simply specify actionname:

```
<form action="actioname">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to post a form to a different action name, you can use the HTML helper for that. In Razor syntax it looks like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("actioname"))
{
  <!-- Form Fields -->
}
```

There are a few parameters you can use - the action is one, another is the controller in case you want to post to an ActionResult in a different controller than the one that handled the request for the page initially.

Answer (score 0):

Yes You can use **actioname** in different controllers and post it:

in any view in any controller you can post:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("actioname", "Controller", FormMethod.Post))
{

}
```